Can the efficacy of an air conditioner be affected by a surge protector?
For years, I have had my 8000 BTU window air conditioner plugged into this CE TECH 8-outlet surge protector.  It was the only item plugged into it.  Recently, I switch it to this TROND 13-outlet surge protector, still by itself.
Starting the night I switched it and for several days now, my room has seemed significantly warmer than it should be.  Even accounting for this by setting the air conditioner several degrees cooler than I otherwise would, I've woken up hot throughout the night several times.  I do not have a baseline quantification of the temperature to verify if it really is warmer than before given identical settings, or just my perception, the humidity, etc., as the temperature setting has never been consistent when measured using other devices, and I don't know if the offset is constant.  As I have always kept the fan on continuously rather than using the Eco mode, and the sound of the cooling mechanism + the fan is rather subtle relative to the fan alone, I also cannot tell if the cooling mechanism is active for shorter or fewer time intervals.
Is it plausible that the two surge protectors may be supplying different quantities of power (if that's the right term) to the air conditioner causing it to cool the room differently, or would a surge protector necessarily give the air conditioner as much power as it needed to operate at maximum efficacy, or else no power at all (in case of overload)?  What metric, if any, is used to convey this information regarding the total power capacity of the surge protector, and does the fact that the new surge protector has more outlets, even though they're unused, still entail that the total power capacity is divided between them, leaving less power for each outlet?

Did you have lightning strikes coincidentally?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

even though they're unused, still entail that the total power capacity is divided between them ... that is not correct

@D.A.S. Nope, no lightning.

If you've felt hot at night for several days have you considered that you have an illness or some kind of minor medical problem. Rule out perception by buying an inexpensive room thermometer is my advice. Do you mean efficacy or efficiency?


Can the efficacy of an air conditioner be affected by a surge protector?

No apparent reasons can explain that. However, a lightning strike that exceeds the 4kJ rating might cause problems for electronics.
But since every outlet has one, and all are in parallel the overvoltage protection is about 13x4 = 52kJ.  If that occurred you would know about it, with tripped breakers and nearby thunder from a direct hit or pretty close to it unless your power company had a serious problem regulating over-voltage.
Powerstrips use MOV's which have a limited lifespan to absorb overvoltage impulses from nearby lightning induces voltages or grid switch transients.  The rating on your power strip link indicates 4000J per outlet which is a good size for typical overvoltage protection. They will fail open-circuit and/or trip the circuit breaker initially if the transient exceeds the component rating.
This means there is no chance for your aircon to run yet not function properly.
4,000 Joules is 400 kW (!) for 10 ms or 4kW for 1s. [J] = [W-s]
Check the manual for servicing like dust filters and evidence of frost on condensers.
